# C++ boost thread, is the following a legit memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, malloc, boost-thread

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <malloc.h>

class callable {
  public:
    void operator()() {
      std::cout << "Thread Run" << std::endl;
    }
}

void run() {
  callable c;
  boost::thread t(boost::ref(c));
  t.join();
}

int main() {
  int alloc = mallinfo().uordblks;
  run();
  int leaked = mallinfo().uordblks - alloc;
  if(leaked)
    std::cout << "mem leak: " << leaked << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It does print "mem leak: 336" on the screen, can someone please explain why is it?
I'd expect that 'leaked' will be 0.

Comment: This function mallinfo is not specified by POSIX or the C standards. I really doubt this function.

Comment: I suggest making `alloc` a global var and adding code similar to `cout << "Mem status: " << mallinfo().uordblks - alloc << std::endl;` at various points in your program.  This may help you determine where the memory is leaking.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis Well, in this code example if you'd comment out the thread instantiation then the "leaked" memory is 0.

Comment: That would seem to be a clue.

Answer (score 0):

On a 64-bit system with a 32-bit C int type, the int fields in struct mallinfo may 
overflow and either wrap around to small or negative values, or hopefully cap at 
INT_MAX. This is a known C library problem and Devel::Mallinfo doesn't try to do 
anything about it. Please check the link below:

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Mallinfo](http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aMallinfo)

I will suggest you using other functions accepted by POSIX or C Standards..